# HyperLink not clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I declared a hyperlink in asp.net as follows;

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hyp" runat="server" Text="new user"></asp:HyperLink>
```

but, I am not getting the underline link, where I could click on it and go to a new page.

```
HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
hyp.ID = "hyp";
hyp.NavigateUrl = "http://localhost/";
hyp.Visible = true;
Page.Controls.Add(hyp);
```

Comment: Those 2 methods of declaring a link are independent of each other.  If you already have the `<asp:hyperlink ... />` tag in your page why are you creating it in code?

Comment: On which event do you execute code? (OnLoad, OnInit, etc ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the link multiple times.

The first time is in your `ASPX`-page. This time only the `ID`- and `Text`-property are set.

The second time you create a new link, and this time you do not set the `Text`-property (which is mandatory), by using:

```
HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
hyp.ID = "hyp";
```

and

```
Page.Controls.Add(hyp);
```

**Your code-behind should just contain:**

```
hyp.NavigateUrl = "http://localhost/";
```

This part is optional, but based on your example does not seem necessary:

```
hyp.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e75sxasw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should also set the `Text` property. Maybe the way you are declaring it in both the webpage and the code behind is confusing things.

Comment: The way he is doing it on the code-behind is not only confusing, it shouldn't be done like that at all.. He only needs line 3 of that code.